generated base64 string is corrupt
I am using CameraX to take photos and want their base64 value. And for that, I want a JPEG base64 string but when I went to view it, it is corrupt and can only be viewed/decoded back to image after I repair it in some online service. Not sure what I am doing wrong:
fun getBase64(
    bmpImg: Bitmap,
): String {

    val byteArrayOutputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()
    bmpImg.compress(
        Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,
        50,
        byteArrayOutputStream,
    )

    val byteArray: ByteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray()

    // Encode the byte array as a Base64 string
    return Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT)
}

I am using JPEG as PNG generates way too big base64.

Why don't you name the service you use? Understanding what type of corruption occurs may help you to understand what is going wrong, therefore you should create a small example base64 code and include it inzknyour question.
